# In google sheets, is there a way to combine columns from separate two different sheets for a pie chart?

Tags: google-sheets, pie-chart

I have a google sheet to track my running for the year. I have [a separate sheet for each month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abEYW.png), and
[each sheet has my miles run each day, how long it took me, and where I ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ql4y.png).

I have another sheet that takes data from all the month sheets and aggregates it to give me stats for the whole year. On this sheet, [I have a pie chart that shows me how many miles I've run at each location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4pm7.png).

My problem is, I can only give the pie chart data from one of the month sheets, because it will only accept a single column for the data ranges for the labels and the values. If I click on label or value in the [chart editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt3FE.png) to enter a data range, and try to enter a range that combines the columns from more than one of my month sheets, [it tells me "One column required"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwvAU.png).

How do I combine the columns from multiple sheets for the data ranges for the labels/values on this pie chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant do this directly in the chart editor. you need to create a sheet where you will use QUERY or FILTER to get all data from your monthly sheets and then you can make chart from it.

something like:

```
=QUERY({Jan!A2:F; Feb!A2:F; Mar!A2:F; Apr!A2:F; May!A2:F; Jun!A2:F; 
        Jul!A2:F; Aug!A2:F; Sep!A2:F; Oct!A2:F; Nov!A2:F; Dec!A2:F}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! QUERY is just what I needed. I ended up using `=QUERY({Jan!C2:D32;Feb!C2:D29;Mar!C2:D32;Apr!C2:D31;May!C2:D32;Jun!C2:D31;Jul!C2:D32;Aug!C2:D32;Sep!C2:D31;Oct!C2:D32;Nov!C2:D31;Dec!C2:D32}, "select Col1, Col2 where Col1 is not null")` to pull all the data into two columns in a separate sheet and used that to build that chart.